# Laravel Eloquent the same queries

Tags: php, laravel, oop, eloquent

I've faced this question on the interview recently.

```
$a = Flight::find(1); 
$b = Flight:find(1);
```

How many objects will be created? How many db queries will be executed?
I'll be thankful so much for any detailed explanation

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site to get free coaching for interviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Either one of the code above, the query will just be 1

`$a = Flight::find(1);`  is same as

```sql
select * from `flights` where `flights`.`id` = 1 limit 1`
```

Since $a & $b are 2 different variables, though they are calling the same Eloquent function, the queries are different. So the code above will result in 2 queries.

Also object created will be 2.

See here for more about Laravel Eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Comment: there is no typo here. That's kinda like trick question

Comment: @Alex then there are 2 different queries. I will update my answer to reflect that. First query for $a and second for $b

Comment: thanks a lot. And how many objects will be created ? 2 as well?

Comment: @Alex Yep, That's right. 2 different objects, though technically the data is same. You are welcome